# jar selective file lising

Tags: java, jar, wildcard

I list the contents of my jar file like this:

```
jar -tf myjar.jar
```

but I want to list selectively e.g. all files starting with 'm'. The following does not work:

```
jar -tf myjar.jar m*
```

I can list all files in a folder:

```
jar -tf myjar.jar folder/
```

but not the files beginning with 'm':

```
jar -tf myjar.jar folder/m*
```

Is there a way for me to filter the listed files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `grep` or `egrep` or similar command line utility, e.g.,

```
jar -tf myjar.jar | grep "folder/m"
```

The `jar` command itself has no support for operations like this. Using tools like `grep`/`egrep`/etc are a canonical solution, and are essential tools anyway.

Comment: Still, your solution will match `abacaba/qqqforder/mmmm`, but surely OP wants to have only lnes, starting with this line, so it would be better to use `egrep` tool with `^` modifier.

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg As the question is written it's impossible to know if `folder/` is at the root, and if it's unique, it doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg ... Because what the OP wrote is already covered without any regexes required? Because it's not that important based on the OP's needs, and seems to have been adequate?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` command along with `jar` command. This will not give you exact result for file name starting pattern but you can get close.

**Without `find` command**

```
C:\jdk1.7.0_72\jre\lib>jar -tf jce.jar
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/ORACLE_J.SF
META-INF/ORACLE_J.RSA
META-INF/
javax/crypto/
javax/crypto/ExemptionMechanismSpi.class
javax/crypto/CryptoPolicyParser$ParsingException.class
javax/crypto/CryptoPolicyParser$GrantEntry.class
javax/crypto/CryptoPolicyParser.class
javax/crypto/JceSecurity$1.class
javax/crypto/CryptoPermissions.class
javax/crypto/AEADBadTagException.class
javax/crypto/NullCipherSpi.class
javax/crypto/EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.class
javax/crypto/ShortBufferException.class
javax/crypto/CipherInputStream.class
javax/crypto/SecretKey.class
javax/crypto/JarVerifier$JarHolder.class
javax/crypto/extObjectInputStream.class
javax/crypto/CipherSpi.class
javax/crypto/KeyGenerator.class
javax/crypto/JceSecurity$2.class
javax/crypto/interfaces/
javax/crypto/interfaces/PBEKey.class
javax/crypto/interfaces/DHPrivateKey.class
javax/crypto/interfaces/DHKey.class
javax/crypto/interfaces/DHPublicKey.class
javax/crypto/IllegalBlockSizeException.class
javax/crypto/CryptoPolicyParser$CryptoPermissionEntry.class
javax/crypto/Cipher$Transform.class
javax/crypto/MacSpi.class
javax/crypto/spec/
javax/crypto/spec/SecretKeySpec.class
javax/crypto/spec/DHParameterSpec.class
javax/crypto/spec/PBEParameterSpec.class
javax/crypto/spec/DHPublicKeySpec.class
javax/crypto/spec/RC5ParameterSpec.class
javax/crypto/spec/IvParameterSpec.class
javax/crypto/spec/RC2ParameterSpec.class
javax/crypto/spec/GCMParameterSpec.class
javax/crypto/spec/DHPrivateKeySpec.class
javax/crypto/spec/OAEPParameterSpec.class
javax/crypto/spec/PBEKeySpec.class
javax/crypto/spec/DESKeySpec.class
javax/crypto/spec/PSource.class
javax/crypto/spec/DHGenParameterSpec.class
javax/crypto/spec/DESedeKeySpec.class
javax/crypto/spec/PSource$PSpecified.class
javax/crypto/JceSecurityManager$1.class
javax/crypto/SecretKeyFactory.class
javax/crypto/ExemptionMechanismException.class
javax/crypto/BadPaddingException.class
javax/crypto/JceSecurity.class
javax/crypto/JarVerifier$2.class
javax/crypto/CryptoAllPermissionCollection.class
javax/crypto/NullCipher.class
javax/crypto/KeyAgreementSpi.class
javax/crypto/CryptoAllPermission.class
javax/crypto/KeyGeneratorSpi.class
javax/crypto/JarVerifier$1.class
javax/crypto/ExemptionMechanism.class
javax/crypto/JceSecurityManager.class
javax/crypto/KeyAgreement.class
javax/crypto/NoSuchPaddingException.class
javax/crypto/CryptoPermissionCollection.class
javax/crypto/PermissionsEnumerator.class
javax/crypto/Mac.class
javax/crypto/SealedObject.class
javax/crypto/Cipher.class
javax/crypto/CryptoPermission.class
javax/crypto/CipherOutputStream.class
javax/crypto/SecretKeyFactorySpi.class
javax/crypto/JarVerifier.class
sun/security/internal/interfaces/
sun/security/internal/interfaces/TlsMasterSecret.class
sun/security/internal/spec/
sun/security/internal/spec/TlsMasterSecretParameterSpec.class
sun/security/internal/spec/TlsKeyMaterialParameterSpec.class
sun/security/internal/spec/TlsKeyMaterialSpec.class
sun/security/internal/spec/TlsRsaPremasterSecretParameterSpec$1.class
sun/security/internal/spec/TlsPrfParameterSpec.class
sun/security/internal/spec/TlsRsaPremasterSecretParameterSpec.class
```

**With `find` command:**

```
C:\jdk1.7.0_72\jre\lib>jar -tf jce.jar | find "Key"
javax/crypto/EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.class
javax/crypto/SecretKey.class
javax/crypto/KeyGenerator.class
javax/crypto/interfaces/PBEKey.class
javax/crypto/interfaces/DHPrivateKey.class
javax/crypto/interfaces/DHKey.class
javax/crypto/interfaces/DHPublicKey.class
javax/crypto/spec/SecretKeySpec.class
javax/crypto/spec/DHPublicKeySpec.class
javax/crypto/spec/DHPrivateKeySpec.class
javax/crypto/spec/PBEKeySpec.class
javax/crypto/spec/DESKeySpec.class
javax/crypto/spec/DESedeKeySpec.class
javax/crypto/SecretKeyFactory.class
javax/crypto/KeyAgreementSpi.class
javax/crypto/KeyGeneratorSpi.class
javax/crypto/KeyAgreement.class
javax/crypto/SecretKeyFactorySpi.class
sun/security/internal/spec/TlsKeyMaterialParameterSpec.class
sun/security/internal/spec/TlsKeyMaterialSpec.class
```

Comment: It it for Windows? You should specify so not to confuse unix-like users, for whom `find` is a tool for finding files under file tree.

Comment: Yes, it is for Windows. It was not mentioned in his question if he wanted Unix, so I presumed Windows box. Even his tags were having only "java", "jar" and "wildcard", no mention of Unix.

Comment: So do you think, that Windows is default option?

Comment: @hagrawal No mention of Windows, either. In either case, Windows users should install a `grep` version anyway, IMO, either through cygwin, or native.

Comment: This works OK (it was windows) but the grep solution posted below is better.